# Php executable for php-linter when using xampp (ubuntu) not working

Tags: php, ubuntu, xampp, atom-editor, linter

As the topic sentence says. I'm using atom with linter-php in ubuntu with an xampp setup. PHP is located in the opt/lampp/bin folder when you've installed xampp in ubuntu 16 but atom isn't accepting it. "unable to get version" and "spawn php ENOENT." Anyone out there using this same setup? Which path did you use for the php executable? Alternatively: Should i just install php in the standard file directory outside of xampp as well and direct linter there?

Answer (score 0):

This may have been a bit of a hack approach to fixing this issue but i just installed php7.0 outside of xampp again and directed the linter path there.  Actually didn't have to direct it at all.  As soon as i installed php from the terminal, the issue was fixed.